# Select, sum, insert, if exist update with MySql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

im trying to do trigger that will before delete select `time` and `id_use` from `tab1`and insert into `tab2` but when in `tab1` are a few same `id_use` it will sum time and then insert to `tab2`, to this point i know how to do this, thats my query

`INSERT INTO tab2 (id_user, time) SELECT id_use, SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( time ) ) ) AS suma FROM tab1 GROUP BY id_use HAVING COUNT(*) > 0`

but now comes tricky part (for me), if in `tab2` already exist same `id_user` i must sum value that is already in `tab1` with new value, if there is no user with this id just insert. I tried with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` but didnt work out Sorry for my poor english and thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Should i ask why can't you use a backend language like php for this??

Then just make a query like: `Select id_use FROM tab1 WHERE id_use='xy';`

And then use a `mysql_num_rows()`
Then:

```
if(num_rows > 0){
      //update it
    }else{
      //insert it
    }
```

But if you want, you can try this: `INSERT INTO tab2 (id_user, time) SELECT id_use, SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( time ) ) ) AS suma FROM tab1 GROUP BY id_use HAVING COUNT(*) > 0 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE time=(SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC( time) ) ) FROM tab1)`

Comment: Thanks for help. It is for school project so i must do as much as possible in mysql, i modified your query `INSERT INTO tab2 (id_user, time) SELECT id_use, SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( time ) ) ) AS suma FROM tab1 GROUP BY id_use HAVING COUNT(*) > 0 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE time=(time + (SELECT id_use, SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( time ) ) ) AS suma FROM tab1 GROUP BY id_use HAVING COUNT(*) > 0))`                                               but now im getting error #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Try this: `INSERT INTO tab2 (id_user, time) SELECT id_use, SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( time ) ) ) AS suma FROM tab1 GROUP BY id_use HAVING COUNT(*) > 0 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE time=(time + (SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( time ) ) ) AS suma FROM tab1 GROUP BY id_use HAVING COUNT(*) > 0))`